# Checking if there exist two set which are equal

Tags: algorithm, set

I have a set `J` of customers and a set of facilities `I`. For each customer `j` there are `K_j<=|I|` *different* distances to facilities. Let these (sorted) distances be `D_j^1 <  D_j^2 < ... < D_j^ {K_j}`. For each distance we define a set of facilities being closer than (in the soft sense) than `D_j^k` units of distance from customer j. This set is given by `V_j^k={ i\in I | d_{ij}<=D_j^k }`. My question is, is there a smart way to check if there exists `i,j,k,l` such that `V_j^K=V_i^l`? It can be assumed that the indices in `V_j^k` are sorted. My only solution is something like

```
for(j in J) do
  for(k in {1,...,K[j]} ) do
    V=V[j][k];
      for(i in J\{j} )
        for(l in {1,...,K[i]} ) do
          compare(V,V[i][l])
```

where the compare function just compares the entries in the two sets. But this has a very high running time. Are there some brilliant ways of performing this task?

Comment: A minor suggestion: The problem will be more easily comprehended if you give more meaningful names to your variables.

Comment: Did you try storing your sets in a hashtable or something?

Answer (score 1):

You have a matrix (M), where a row corresponds to a customer. The elements of this matrix are sets of facilities. M_cf = the set containing the f closest facility to customer c. In this matrix, the elements of the first column will be sets containing only one facility, which is always the closest facility to the customer. In the second column, every set will have 2 facilities, etc. Now we will find sets that have the same facilities. These sets must be in the same column, otherwise the number of elements in each set would be different, so the sets couldnt be equal. In a column f, you would normally need to compare all sets to all other sets to find equal sets, which would result in O(f^2) time complexity. You can reduce it to O(f*log(f)) if you instead sort the sets in this column using an appropriate algorithm. The total time complexity will be O(j*f*log(f)), which is way better than your current O(j^2*f^2), assuming O(1) compare.